# Access SQL: Union query that generates pop-up

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

**Situation:** I have three tables of parts: Raw Material, Individual Parts, and Assembled Parts. I have created a union query to list all the part numbers as well as their minimum levels of inventory and and opening levels of inventory. I also have an inventory table that uses all the part numbers. I this used the union query to find current inventory and a current balance in another query. When I attempt to open this query I get a input box asking for CurrentInventory.

**Question:** How do I get the input box to stop appearing?

**Code:**

*Tables:* 
Raw Material, Individual Parts, and Assembled Parts all have similar formats that begin with the following

```
PartNum | Min | Open
1         50    100
```

Inventory:

```
PartNum  | Year | Week | In | Out
1          2015   31     20   10
```

*Queries*
Union Query:

```
SELECT PartNum, Open, Min
FROM Raw Material
UNION 
SELECT PartNum , Open, Min
FROM Individual Parts
UNION 
SELECT PartNum, Open, Min 
FROM Assembled Parts;
```

Which results in:

```
PartNum | Min | Open
1         50    100
etc.
```

Current Inventory:

```
SELECT AllParts.PartNum, AllParts.Open, Sum(Inventory.[In]) AS SumOfIn, 
       Sum(Inventory.Out) AS SumOfOut, 
       [Open]+[SumOfIn]-[SumOfOut] AS CurrentInventory, 
       AllParts.Min, [CurrentInventory]-[Min] AS CurrentBalance
FROM AllParts 
     INNER JOIN Inventory ON AllParts.PartNum = Inventory.PartNum
GROUP BY AllParts.PartNum, AllParts.Open, AllParts.Min, 
         [CurrentInventory]-[Min], [Open]+[In]-[Out];
```

When I attempt to run this is when I get the input box for CurrentInventory. If I don't enter anything it doesn't effect the results. However, when I attempt to run the report I generate from this, the column will show as what I entered and not the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are aliasing a calculated result as "CurrentInventory", you can't reference that calculation by the alias in the same query.
Everytime you have "CurrentInventory" (except for after the "AS") you need to replace it with `[Open]+[SumOfIn]-[SumOfOut]`